# Content-Type setting for .MTS files

Tags: perl, cgi

In my application i like to provide file download facility. How can I set the content types for .MTS files.

for example:

```
if ($fileName =~ /\.pdf$/i) { ## for pdf files
    print "Content-Type: application/pdf", "\n";
    print "Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=$fileName", "\n\n";
    print $File;
}elsif($fileName =~ /\.zip$/i){ 
    print "Content-type: application/zip", "\n";
    print "Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=$fileName", "\n\n";
    print $File;
}
elsif($fileName =~ /\.(mpg|mp3|mp4|swf|wmv|avi)$/i){
    print "Content-type: application/mp3", "\n";
    print "Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=$fileName", "\n\n";
    print $File;
}
```

MTS is a file extension for an AVCHD (Advanced Video Coding High Definition) video clip format for high-definition video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use correct MIME-TYPE for .MTS.

Below MIME types are supported:

```
application/metastream, video/avchd-stream, video/mts, video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer, considering OP said "MTS is a file extension for an AVCHD (Advanced Video Coding High Definition) video clip format for high-definition video."
You provided the answer for some "Virtue MTS" file type.

Answer (score 4):

The proper mime-type for the [MPEG-2 Transport Stream (.mts)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mts) should be `video/MP2T`, according to [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3555#section-4.2.9).